# Local settings in javascript project

Tags: javascript, django, backbone.js, settings, conventions

I am working on an open source javascript project using backbone that uses a bunch of global settings. For local development, we'd like for each developer to be able to set their own settings, but we want this to exist in a separate file so we can exclude it from the repository using .gitignore.

I come from a Django background and the convention is to have a settings.py and local_settings.py where settings.py simply does something like:

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
except:
    pass
```

Is there an equivalent javascript convention for local settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, simply create a global object (or local to your namespace if you have one) containing all the settings:

```
var settings = {
    ...
};
```

Since globals are really global in JavaScript and not module-specific like in python there is no need to import anything.

If you want to extend/overwrite your settings object, you can e.g. use jQuery's [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) method:

```
var currentSettings = $.extend(true, {}, settings, localSettings);
```

Comment: So should the localSettings object live in its own javascript file? And if so, how do you ensure that it gets loaded into the global namespace without causing an error if the user has not created localSettings.js?

Comment: Doesn't matter in which file it is. If it might be undefined: `typeof localSettings == 'undefined' ? {} : localSettings`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what kind of settings you would like to export to js and why. In any case if you want to do that I guess the simplest would be to have a json view in django serving the settings to your javascript. That way at least you can have *one* place for storing the settings.

I am no Django dev but I would guess something like

```
from json import dumps
from django.http import HttpResponse

...

def json_settings(request):
    json = dumps(local_settings)
    return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/json')
```

would do the job. You can then obtain these settings by calling `$.getJSON`

Comment: Sorry I was probably unclear in that this is purely a javascript project, and that I just happen to come from a Django background. Still, thanks for the interesting idea if I do need to integrate with a Django project and do something like this.